# Angular 4 firebase dropdown select tag option

Tags: html, angularjs, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Angular 4 and firebase. I'm trying to build a dropdown selector for a list of properties.

Once a property is selected from the dropdown list, the property location should appear in another input field below.

**properties.component.html**

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedProperty" (change)="onSelect($event, property)">
    <option>--select property--</option>
    <option *ngFor="let property of properties">{{property.propertyName}}</option>
  </select>

<div *ngIf="selectedProperty">
    <label >Location </label>
    <input type="text" value="{{selectedProperty.location}}">
</div>
```

**properties.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { PropertyService } from './../services/property.service';
import { Property } from './../models/property';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-property-list',
  templateUrl: './property-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./property-list.component.scss']
})
export class PropertyListComponent implements OnInit {

  properties: Observable<Property[]>;
  selectedProperty: Property;

  constructor(private propertyService: PropertyService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.propertyService.getProperties().subscribe(properties => {
      this.properties = properties;
    })
  }

  onSelect(event, property: Property){
    this.selectedProperty = property;
  }

}
```

I am able to select the property from the dropdown list but the property location does not appear on the input field. I'll appreciate your help.

Comment: You could use <input type="text" [value]="selectedProperty.location"> , this I believe that would solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Instead of value use ngModel

```
<div *ngIf="selectedProperty">
    <label >Location </label>
    <input type="text"  [(ngModel)]="selectedProperty.location">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default selecting option from dropdown selects whatever value provided in selected `option` tag. So when you select any value in dropdown it puts`propertyName` inside respective `ngModel`.

As you want to select the whole object use `ngValue` in option, what that will do is, when user selects an option it will take down `ngValue` object value and assigned it to ngModel of `select` field.

```
<option [ngValue]="property" *ngFor="let property of properties">
  {{property.propertyName}}
</option>
```